# A comparison between 'utilize', 'use' and 'waste'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Please imagine someone uses his energy doing some useless and mainly worthless things and you are going to advise him and as a friend give him a warning that what he is doing is wasting his time. I was wondering if someone could let me know which one of the following choices sounds more idiomatic in the self-made sentence below and finally tell me if my sentence is natural at all or I have to rephrase it:

> - Don’t.............your energy for worthless things.
>
> a) utilize
>
> b) waste
>
> c) use

For me, depending on the context, both 'b' and 'c' sound idiomatic.

Comment: For me waste is better, because wasted is not a useful thing, but "use" may be used for useful or useless.

Comment: _Don't waste your energy **on**..._, not _Don't waste your energy for...._